# Availability of software for stitching hyperspectral images captured from a top-down hyperspectral video

Tags: image-stitching

Is there a software available and accessible to others for stitching hyperspectral images captured from a top-down hyperspectral video of plants, in order to create a panoramic view of the plants?

Comment: There are thoughts of implementing multi band Support in the stitching package: https://github.com/orgs/OpenStitching/discussions/86

Comment: Maybe you want to join the disussion